# How to fix 'cannot assign to Partial<this>' in subclass method?

Tags: typescript

If I invoke the base class's `update` method via a subclass instance it works, but it gives me this error if I do it inside a subclass method:

> Argument of type '{ prop: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<this>'.

```js
class Base {
    update(modifier: Partial<this>) {
        Object.keys(modifier).forEach(key => {
            this[key] = modifier[key];
        });
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    prop;

    job() {
        // Error: Argument of type '{ prop: number; }' is not assignable 
        // to parameter of type 'Partial<this>'.ts(2345)
        this.update({ prop: 1 });
    }
}

new Sub().update({ prop: 1 }); // but it works here!
```

[Live on the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update(modifier%3A%20Partial%3Cthis%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.keys(modifier).forEach(key%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20modifier%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Sub%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20job()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%7B%20prop%3A%20number%3B%20%7D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'Partial%3Cthis%3E'.ts(2345)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.update(%7B%20prop%3A%201%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Sub().update(%7B%20prop%3A%201%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20but%20it%20works%20here!).

How do I fix it?

Comment: I know it's tangential to the question, but just FWIW, the body of `update` can be simply: `Object.assign(this, modifier);`. But I'm fascinated by the error and hoping you get a good answer for the actual question. Even more bizarrely (to me), even if you add an `update` to `Sub` with the same signature as the base version, the error persists.

Comment: this.update.call(this, {prop:1}) works, however

Comment: @DC `call` is probably untyped, if you use `strictBindCallApply` you get the same error

Comment: That part isn't surprising, the type information on `call` is defined as accepting a rest array of `any`.

Comment: I don't know what version of TypeScript the playground is using, but I can confirm that this still happens in TypeScript v3.5.1 (the latest as of this writing).

Comment: **call** definition in lib.es5.d.ts is:   call<T, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: A): R;

Comment: @DC i get an error with call if I enable `strictBindCallApply` otherwise the untyped definition of call is used

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hope the answer is good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphic `this` is not a regular type it is in fact a type parameter to your class. A hidden type parameter that is managed by the compiler, but a type parameter nonetheless. Since `this` is just a type parameter, with a constraint of extending the current class (something like `class Base<This extends Base> {}`) it is not fully known inside the class.

There are many questions on SO about why we can't assign a value to a variable of a generic type parameter, or why conditional/mapped types don't work well with generic type parameters. For example this does not work either:

```
function partial<T extends { prop: number }>(): Partial<T> {
    return { prop: 1 }
}
```

The reason this general class of issues do not work, is that we only know the minimal interface `T` must implement, we don't know `T` fully. Consider this example:

```
function getObj<T extends { prop: { name: string } }>(): Partial<T> {
    return { prop: { name: "" } }// still an error
}
var r = getObj<{ prop: { name: string, lastName: string}}>();
r.prop!.lastName // r should have last name, where is my lastName ?!
```

`prop` in `T` is constrained to have `name`, but it could have more props as shown by the valid call below. We would expect `r` to respect the `T` passed in but in fact the value returned is not valid for the given `T`. To prevent such surprises, typescript does not generally allow us to assign concrete value where a type parameter is involved (since we don't really know the final shape of the type parameter)

Coming back to polymorphic `this`, the above reasoning holds, `this` is a type parameter that is not fully known and thus an object literal can't be assigned to it since we don't know the final shape of `this`.

Consider a similar example to the one above:

```
class Base {
    update(modifier: Partial<this>) {
        Object.keys(modifier).forEach(key => {
            this[key] = modifier[key];
        });
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    prop! :{
        name: string
    };

    job() {
        this.update({ prop: { name: string } }); // not valid for any class, example below
    }
}

class Sub2 extends Sub {
    prop! : {
        name: string
        lastName: string
    };
}
```

I chose to replace `number` with an object type as it is easier to understand the issue, but similar type issues can occur with `number`. Number could be a number literal type in derived classes.

Outside of the class polymorphic `this` is known (much like it would be known in the call to a generic function) this is why the call succeeds outside the class.

```
new Sub().update({ prop: 1 }); // this is Sub for this call so Partial<Sub> is { prop?: number }
```

Inside the class polymorphic `this` could be `Sub` or any derived class of `Sub`. Outside `this` collapses to just the specific type reference the function was invoked on (this is not 100% sound either but it is a compromise to make this useful)

The only way to fix this issue is to either use a type assertion and accept that this is not type safe. Or use a second type parameter that represent the props of the class, although this will mean your inheritance hierarchy can have only one level where new props can be added.

```
class Base<TProps> {
    update(modifier: Partial<TProps>) {
        Object.assign(this, modifier);
    }
}

class Sub extends Base<Sub> {
    prop: number;

    job() {
        this.update({ prop: 1 });
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please further explain why the last line of my code works however? @Titian

Comment: Outside the class the type parameter is know, it can't be any type anymore, it is specifically `Sub` so the compiler knows the shape of `this` for this call

Comment: I wonder how this can be known outside class but not inside class. Where can I learn that?

Comment: @DC - Inside the class, `this` might be of a further subclass type (`SubSub`, `SubSubSub`, etc.). But in your call at the end, `new Sub()` is definitely a `Sub`, not a subclass of `Sub`.

Comment: @DC added more explanation in the answer, as well as an alternative, hope it makes things a bit more clear

Comment: What bothers me about this is that as of `this.update({prop: 1})`, `this` is definitely either `Sub` or a subclass of it (barring games with `call` or `apply`). Surely `{prop: 1}` is then known to be a partial of `Sub`...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not really, for object types it is definitely not true as I showed in the answer, for primitives, given literal types and intersections.. it is still not true. This is a valid extension of `Sub`: `class Sub extends Base { prop!: number;}
    class SubSub extends Sub { prop: 2  = 2}` So `{prop: 1}` is valid for `Sub` buit not valid for `SubSub`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - That subclass violates the Liskov substitution principle. I wouldn't expect a static type system like TypeScript's to support Liskov violations, much less let that support prevent doing useful things.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with you that is a bit surprising, but the a object subtype in general does subtypes for properties. So while the `number` case is wierd, it is valid subtyping at the moment. I think the object property sub-typing is what is really preventing this from being implemented, and rather than just allowing some properties, a blanket ban is simpler to implement. `this` type is generally wierd and a lot less useful then it seems at first ..

Comment: I actually needed something like `class Sub implements Base<Sub> {` though this is great, thanks!